# How to get only the first item in a list in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `List<String>` and I want to bind a textblock to the first item in that list through xaml only, is there a way to achieve this, if so please provide a sample code.

Comment: `if so please provide a sample code` **you** provide the code and the problem and we fix it. this is the way SO works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your list was called ItemList you can bind to it like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemList[0]}" />
```

This could cause issues if you have an empty list or if the first item gets removed.